# csv import no row is imported

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I get an error when trying to import currencies in csv format into database:

```
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\currencies.csv'
    INTO TABLE `test`.`currencies`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
    (`alpha3`, `number`, `decimals`, `name`, `countries`);
```

The sample csv:

```
alpha3,number,decimals,name,countries
AED,784,2,"United Arab Emirates dirham","[""ARE""]"
AFN,971,2,"Afghan afghani","[""AFG""]"
ALL,008,2,"Albanian lek","[""ALB""]"
AMD,051,2,"Armenian dram","[""ARM""]"
```

I think is because of the countries field.

---

Script to create the table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `currencies` (
    `alpha3` CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    `number` CHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `decimals` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `countries` TEXT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`alpha3`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: /* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.063 sec. */

Comment: Should not it be `ESCAPED BY '""'` - double quotes?

Comment: Please provide the `CREATE TABLE` so we can experiment.

Comment: @RickJames I have edited my question with the Create table script.

Comment: That table does not match that `LOAD`.

Comment: @RickJames opss.. I edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Temp\\currencies.csv'
    ->  INTO TABLE `try`.`currencies`
    ->     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"'
    ->     LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
    ->     (`alpha3`, `number`, `decimals`, `name`, `countries`);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from currencies;
+--------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+-----------+
| alpha3 | number | decimals | name                        | countries |
+--------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+-----------+
| AED    | 784    |        2 | United Arab Emirates dirham | ["ARE"]   |
| AFN    | 971    |        2 | Afghan afghani              | ["AFG"]   |
| ALL    | 008    |        2 | Albanian lek                | ["ALB"]   |
| AMD    | 051    |        2 | Armenian dram               | ["ARM"]   |
+--------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm using version 5.6.12 on Windows.  What version and OS are you using?  (I doubt if the version matters.)

Comment: I am using Mariadb 10.1.10. No error, just nothing get inserted.